# Fill color not working using CAShapeLayer in swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

I am trying below code to draw shape and that's okay but **UIView background color** not showing since I Have given orange color to **View**

See my code:

```
let myView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
myView.backgroundColor = .orange
let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: myView.bounds.size.width / 2, y: 0), radius: myView.bounds.size.height, startAngle: 0.0, endAngle: .pi, clockwise: false)
let circleShape = CAShapeLayer()
circleShape.masksToBounds = false
circleShape.path = circlePath.cgPath
circleShape.fillColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor
circleShape.strokeColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor
myView.layer.mask = circleShape
print(myView)
```

Output At Playground:

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
    let myView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
    myView.backgroundColor = .orange
    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: myView.center,
                                  radius: myView.bounds.size.width / 2,
                                  startAngle: 0.0,
                                  endAngle: .pi,
                                  clockwise: false)
    let circleShape = CAShapeLayer()
    circleShape.path = circlePath.cgPath
    myView.layer.mask = circleShape
```

I think you don't see expecting result because of wrong arcCenter or start and end angels

result of the code:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with your `circlePath`, that has:

1) Wrong arcCenter (CGPoint's `y` is not centered)

2) Radius (It should be half the view's height/width, considering `height = width` and you need a circle)

3) Angle (It should be 360 degrees)

Replace its definition with:

```
let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: myView.center, radius: myView.bounds.height/2, startAngle: 0.0, endAngle: .pi * 2, clockwise: false)
```

and it should work as intended...

> that's okay but UIView background color not showing since I Have given
>   orange color to View

The path you've used doesn't even display a layer since you've specified its corner radius to be the same as its height, and you've applied the generated supposedly invisible layer to be your view's mask.

Answer (score 0):

A few observations:

1. You are just looking at a visual representation of the path, not of the view. To see the view, you should set the `liveView` of the `PlaygroundPage`:

   ```
   import PlaygroundSupport
   ```

   And

   ```
   PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = myView
   PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
   ```
2. An an aside, your circle view is going from 0 to π counterclockwise. I.e. that is the top half of a circle. So if the circle’s center has a `y` of `0`, that means your path is above the view and doesn’t overlap with it. Either set it to go clockwise (to get the bottom half of a circle) or move the `y` down (so the top half half of the circle overlaps the view).
3. I find that playgrounds resize their `liveView` (even if I set `wantsFullScreenLiveView` to `false`), so if I want a view of a particular size, I use a “container view”. I.e., I will add `myView` as a subview of `containerView`, add constraints to put it in the center of that container, and then set `containerView` as the `liveView`.
4. Only tangentially related, but you’re setting the color of the shape layer of the mask to be orange. Masks only use their alpha channel, so using orange is meaningless. We’d generally set masks to be white, but I just wanted to make sure we didn’t conflate the color of the mask with the color of the masked view.

So, pulling that all together:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

// create container
let containerView = UIView()
containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

// create view that we'll mask with shape layer
let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)
let myView = UIView()
myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
myView.backgroundColor = .orange
myView.clipsToBounds = true
containerView.addSubview(myView)

// create mask
let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.minY), radius: rect.height, startAngle: 0, endAngle: .pi, clockwise: true)
let circleShape = CAShapeLayer()
circleShape.masksToBounds = false
circleShape.path = circlePath.cgPath
circleShape.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
circleShape.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
myView.layer.mask = circleShape

// center masked view in container
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    myView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerXAnchor),
    myView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerYAnchor),
    myView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
    myView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200)
])

// show it
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = containerView
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

That yields:

[image]

So, by making the arc go clockwise and by using the `liveView`, we can now see it. Obviously an arc whose center is at `midX, minY` and with a radius of `height`, cannot show the full half circle. You’d have to set the radius to be `width / 2` (or increase the `width` of the `rect` or whatever) if you wanted to see the full half circle.

Answer (score 0):

Just **remove path.move(to:) calls** everywhere after drawing. That's helped me with the same issue